# Disable Javascript for Chrome using Capybara Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable Javascript for some tests using Selenium-webdriver in Chrome with Capybara.

I have the following:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|

  opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  opts.add_argument '--start-maximized'
  opts.add_argument '--disable-infobars'
  opts.add_argument '--disable-features'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: opts)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

But I don't think that `--disable-javascript` works now.

I've tried to find an alternative but to no joy.

Would anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to disable js for selenium-webdriver, however, you can just use `:rack_test`. driver instead.

From `Capybara` documentation:

> By default, Capybara uses the :rack_test driver, which is fast but
>   limited: it does not support JavaScript,

So in your case it can be:

```
it "test description", driver: :rack_test do
  ...
end
```